# SQL - Must there always be a primary key?

Tags: sql

There are a couple of similar questions already out there and the consensus seemed to be that a primary key should always be created.

But what if you have a single row table for storing settings (and let's not turn this into a discussion about why it might be good/bad to create a single row table please)?

Surely having a primary key on a single row table becomes completely useless?

Comment: Are you talking about a logical primary key or the feature in SQL?

Comment: Yes, a primary key on a single row table like the one you describe is unwarranted.  If using MySQL a primary key is created if you don't specify one, so in MySQL there must always be a primary key.

Comment: To get rid of some confusion: `every table has an index of some kind`, because that is just how tables are stored in an RDBMS, `but not every table has to have a primary key`

Comment: You can have whatever you want in your relational database. You can even have several identical rows. But it is not useful in practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may seem completely useless, but it's also completely harmless, and I'd vote for harmless with good design principles vs. useless with no design principles every time.

Other people have commented, rightly, that you don't know how you're going to use the table in a year or five years... what if someone comes along and decides they want to duplicate the configuration -- move it to a distributed environment or add a test environment by using a duplicate configuration string or whatever.  Having a field that acts like a primary key means that whenever you query the table, if you use the key, you'll be certain no matter what anyone else may do to your table, that you're getting the correct record.

You're right there are a million other aspects -- surrogate keys vs. intelligent keys, indexing, partitioning (silly on a single row table, I know), whatever... but without getting into that I'd vote add the key rather than not add it.  You could have done it by the time you read this thread.

Comment: You're right, and I ended up doing it in the end. Simple reason is that at a later version of the application the settings might be different, so I added a `SettingsVersion` column and made that the primary key.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, no key, duplicate records possible.  Your planning a single row now, but what about six months in the future when you single row multiplies.  Put a primary key on the table, even for single row.

Comment: Depending on the RDBMS, which was not specified, the same thing can be accomplished by specifying fields, or maybe combinations thereof to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You could always base your primary key on the name of the setting.  Then your table would become a key-value store.

But no, in many RDBMS you are not REQUIRED to have a primary key per table.

Answer (score 0):

Having declared a primary key on a single row table *in SQL* will ensure that there will be no duplicates. Whether it is useless depends on your requirements. Usually it is a good idea to avoid duplicates.